# Uninstall storage heavy Windows applications like Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer, windows-media-player, windows-media-center

I currently have a 128GB SSD and want as much free space as possible. I want to uninstall some of the software installed by windows, because I use alternative applications.

This is what I want to uninstall:

- Windows Media Center
- Windows Media Player
- Windows DVD Maker
- Internet Explorer

And any other applications that are storage heavy and I really don't have to use.

How can I do this?

Comment: I edited your question to make it a bit more clear, if you are unhappy with the changes you can always revert or edit them again.

Comment: Use this program to customize your W7 installation disc...http://www.rt7lite.com/

Comment: Can I remove WMC, WMP, MDM and internet explorer with this tool?

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall some unneeded programs by going to [Start] [Control panel] [Programs and features] then on the left side select [Turn windows features on or off].

I do not expect that this will save much space though. Windows media player is not storage heavy.  Your music files might be, but just removing an application which plays them will not save much file.

Removing Swap and or hibernate files will save much more room.   ( By default in Windows 7, the size of the hidden hibernation file C:\hiberfil.sys is 75% of the installed RAM on your computer. Use powercfg -h do do this)

Comment: I got rid of hibernation and decreased the size of the page-file the other day, and it saved me >10GB

Comment: Turning Windows features on or off won't actually free up any disk space. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Turn-Windows-features-on-or-off

Comment: I stand corrected. Everyday you learn something new.